# Can I use Tasker to enable and disable WiFi hotspot functionality?

Tags: tasker, wifi-hotspot

I have an Android tablet (Nexus 7) and an Android phone (HTC One) and I use my phone as a WiFi hotspot so that my tablet (which doesn't have it's own internet connection) can access the internet when I'm out and about.

Since running a WiFi hotspot is a very battery intensive activity I was looking at using something like Tasker to disable it under a specific set of conditions;

- Whenever the HTC One is in range of a specific WiFi network (SSID is Pegasus), disable the WiFi hotspot
- Whenever the HTC One is not in range of the same specific WiFi network (SSID is Pegasus), enable the WiFi hotspot
- Whenever the HTC One is outside of range of the Nexus 7, disable the WiFi hotspot

Is this possible with Tasker? I suspect that the first two steps would be but since it's the Nexus 7 connecting to the HTC One and not the other way around the last one might not be possible?

If this isn't possible with Tasker, is there anything that can provide this kind of functionality?

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is the problem still relevant to you? I can possibly post a working answer after getting some details, provided that the issue is still relevant to you.